# How to stream a scheduled playlist of video files

Tags: java, html, webrtc, video-processing, live-streaming

I'm looking for a way or a streaming server that allows streaming a list of local video files to multiple receivers, and all the receivers are synced, so they will all see the same video output at the same time.

I am not focused on a specific programming language or framework, I know there is a way of doing it in Actionscript & FMS , but since Flash is dying I'm not considering it a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that by local video files you actually mean some files hosted on a server. Instead of WebRTC, which is peer-to-peer you'll better be using a [media stream server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_streaming_media_systems) and create some kind of "live" stream for all those files, so that the receivers are synced.

On the client side, just use the video tag with the appropriate URL.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Do you know a media server that syncs videos with time, Doing it from the client side will cause issues with the buffering and it's impossible to sync all receivers to have the same output